# Div scrolling makes padding-bottom disappears

Tags: html, css, scroll, height, padding

I have a site with the following structure:

```
    <div class="main-outer">
     <div class="main-inner">
      <div class="test"> 
        components
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

where the div *'test'* calls the different components.

I´m trying to make it height responsive, so that if the components have 'height:100%', it should grow as the screen grows.
However if i set a min-height in the components, the scroll (from the *main-outer div*) should appear from that height.

**My problem is**: When the screen reachs that min-height, the padding-bottom (or margin) that i set in the *'main-inner class'* disappears... How can i work around this problem?

I have an example here:
https://jsfiddle.net/4o1j2zmn/1/

**Edit**: I need the margin in higher div than the 'test' one, because as i call many components, i want to make the margin a global one

Comment: Did you mean to set the margin-bottom css to 55px? As it's currently 25px.

Comment: It could be any value actually, but even if i put margin-bottom: 200px, it will not work

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your code I think ".main-outer" padding is working fine. It is the issue in ".main-inner" margin and fixed height of the ".test" class. I have shifted your margin property from ".main-inner" to ".test" class and made ".test" height auto so that it will adjust according to the content and also show margin from the outer edge of parent container. Please check and try below snippet :

```css
.main-outer {
  padding: 0 50px;
  height:100vh;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  background-color: blue;
}

.main-inner {
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.test{
      display: block;
    content: '';
    height: auto;
    background-color: red;
    margin: 50px 0 50px 0;
}
```

```html
    <div class="main-outer">
      <div class="main-inner">
        <div class="test">
          http://www.himanshu-joshi.com/ http://www.himanshu-joshi.com/ http://www.himanshu-joshi.com/ http://www.himanshu-joshi.com/ http://www.himanshu-joshi.com/ http://www.himanshu-joshi.com/ http://www.himanshu-joshi.com/ http://www.himanshu-joshi.com/ http://www.himanshu-joshi.com/ http://www.himanshu-joshi.com/ http://www.himanshu-joshi.com/ http://www.himanshu-joshi.com/ http://www.himanshu-joshi.com/ http://www.himanshu-joshi.com/ http://www.himanshu-joshi.com/ http://www.himanshu-joshi.com/ http://www.himanshu-joshi.com/ http://www.himanshu-joshi.com/ http://www.himanshu-joshi.com/ http://www.himanshu-joshi.com/ http://www.himanshu-joshi.com/ http://www.himanshu-joshi.com/ http://www.himanshu-joshi.com/ http://www.himanshu-joshi.com/ http://www.himanshu-joshi.com/ http://www.himanshu-joshi.com/ http://www.himanshu-joshi.com/ http://www.himanshu-joshi.com/ http://www.himanshu-joshi.com/ http://www.himanshu-joshi.com/ http://www.himanshu-joshi.com/ http://www.himanshu-joshi.com/ http://www.himanshu-joshi.com/ http://www.himanshu-joshi.com/ http://www.himanshu-joshi.com/ http://www.himanshu-joshi.com/ http://www.himanshu-joshi.com/ http://www.himanshu-joshi.com/ http://www.himanshu-joshi.com/ http://www.himanshu-joshi.com/ http://www.himanshu-joshi.com/ http://www.himanshu-joshi.com/ http://www.himanshu-joshi.com/ http://www.himanshu-joshi.com/ http://www.himanshu-joshi.com/ http://www.himanshu-joshi.com/ http://www.himanshu-joshi.com/ http://www.himanshu-joshi.com/ http://www.himanshu-joshi.com/ http://www.himanshu-joshi.com/ http://www.himanshu-joshi.com/ http://www.himanshu-joshi.com/ http://www.himanshu-joshi.com/ http://www.himanshu-joshi.com/ http://www.himanshu-joshi.com/ http://www.himanshu-joshi.com/ http://www.himanshu-joshi.com/ http://www.himanshu-joshi.com/ http://www.himanshu-joshi.com/ http://www.himanshu-joshi.com/ 
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but my main problem is that i need the margin in higher div than the 'test' one, because as i call many components, i want to make the margin a global one.